# Why does my oven trip the kitchen circuit fuse?

Tags: appliances

After a recent refurb where some of the electrics were also changed (including consumer unit and a full rewire), I noticed that when using the oven it would *sometimes* trip the kitchen fuse. Where should I start looking? Here's a bits of information:

- The oven is an Indesit DFW 5530 ix UK (not new)
  https://www.electricalspecs.co.uk/indesit-aria-dfw-5530-ix-electric-oven-specs/
- It is connected to a socket with a 13 Amp fused switch
- It is part of the whole kitchen circuit (on a 32 Amp fuse)
- Nothing else on that circuit causes trips (including a combi boiler, washing machine, dish washer, toaster, kettle, etc. They all work fine, even when multiple appliances are on at the same time.)
- When the Kitchen circuit fuse trips, the 13 amp socket switch doesn't blow.
- When connecting the the oven to another circuit (eg livingroom sockets - 32 Amp fuse) via an extension, the same thing has happened there too -- trips it after a while.
- The oven doesn't always trip, it sometimes works fine, but sometimes trips after working for a while, or if when changing settings or temperature.

From all that info is it obvious to anyone what might be going on? Is it just a faulty appliance, which might have worked without tripping the old consumer unit because it was with ancient fuses (possibly not as sensitive), or is something else going on?

Comment: Fuse or RCCB? If the latter, it’s common when the heating element is worn and leaks more current as it heats up (or cools, whichever is the most unfavorable). If fuse, not so clear cut what’s the first thing to look for.

Comment: That oven has two elements (https://www.espares.co.uk/search/mo2452385pt1595/cookers-and-hobs/elements/indesit/dfw5530ixuk), one rated at 1500 W and the other rated at 1150 W, for a total of 2650 W, which will draw about 11 A when they are both on, assuming 240 V. That should definitely not trip the circuit breaker. I would guess that one of the elements is failing and causing an intermittent short circuit. I am not a qualified electrician.

Comment: Happened to me last month. Element tripped the RCCB. It was all swollen and I surmise that the outer metal casing had developed cracks and allowed moisture to enter, compromising the insulation which swelled as the leakage current heated it.

Comment: Fortunately, oven heating elements are pretty cheap and usually easy to replace.

Comment: They typically fail part way through the life of the oven.

Comment: @winny RCCB is what I was thinking of when i say "fuse". Thanks, will try changing the heating element.

Answer (score 2):

With ovens, it is often a problem with a heating element.  The elements are metal tubes, filled with a mineral powder insulation.  A heating wire runs down the middle.

If the oven hasn't been used for a while, damp can get into the mineral insulation.  This can cause an RCD or RCBO to trip.

Or, as others have said in the comments, the heating element can break down over time.  The outer tube splits, and the heating element comes into contact with it.  This could trip and RCD or circuit breaker.